# sort dictionary alphabetically by key in odoo 13

Tags: python, odoo

I have built a dictionary to collect orders according to the client, the products that have been ordered and I need to order it alphabetically by client to use it in a qweb report, nothing I have tried so far has worked for me. Any ideas?

```
reparto_data = {
    'Cliente 1': {
       'Pastel manzana': 12,
       'Bomba crema': 8,
    },

    'Cliente 2': {
       'Cake calabaza': 18,
       'Bombon chocolate': 8,
    },

    #...
}

reparto_data2 = {}
for i in sorted(reparto_data[key]):
    reparto_data2[i] = reparto_data[i]
```

Comment: You had an extra backtick at the end; and the elipsis ... made for illegal Python. I fixed these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help but I have posed the question wrong since the dictionary contains objects.

The code that has worked for me is the following:

reparto_data2 = sorted(reparto_data.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower())

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the inner dictionaries.

So, iterate across the keys and values of the outer dict, and for each value (which is an inner dict), sort it.

```
from pprint import pprint

reparto_data = {
    'Cliente 1': {
        'Pastel manzana': 12,
        'Bomba crema': 8,
    },

    'Cliente 2': {
        'Cake calabaza': 18,
        'Bombon chocolate': 8,
    },
}

def sort_dict(d):
    return {k: d[k] for k in sorted(d.keys())}

reparto_data2 = {k: sort_dict(v) for k,v in reparto_data.items()}
pprint(reparto_data2, width=1)
```

Output

```
{'Cliente 1': {'Bomba crema': 8,
               'Pastel manzana': 12},
 'Cliente 2': {'Bombon chocolate': 8,
               'Cake calabaza': 18}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too.

```
reparto_data = {
    'Cliente 1': {
        'Pastel manzana': 12,
        'Bomba crema': 8,
    },
    'Cliente 2': {
        'Cake calabaza': 18,
        'Bombon chocolate': 8,
    },
}

sorted_clients = sorted(reparto_data.keys(), key=lambda x:x.lower())

reparto_data2 = {i: reparto_data[i] for i in sorted_clients}
```

Output

```
{'Cliente 1': {'Pastel manzana': 12, 'Bomba crema': 8}, 'Cliente 2': {'Cake calabaza': 18, 'Bombon chocolate': 8}}
```

If want to use your own code just replace this with your **loop**

```
reparto_data2 = {i: reparto_data[i] for i in sorted(reparto_data[key])}
```